# How to make this list a circular list?

Tags: c

The code is the next, I would like for the last item in the list to aim with a pointer to the beginning of the list all the time, even if I change it or remove it, but I don know how. I'm kind of new to this.

This is the full code I have, with functions to insert and remove the elements in the list as well with a function for instructions and to print

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode {
    char data;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode LISTNODE;
typedef LISTNODE *LISTNODEPTR;

char delete(LISTNODEPTR *, char);
int isEmpty(LISTNODEPTR);
void printList(LISTNODEPTR);
void instructions(void);
LISTNODE *addtoList(LISTNODEPTR *sPtr, char value);

int main() {
    LISTNODEPTR startPtr = NULL;
    int choice;
    char item;

    instructions();
    printf("? ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice != 3) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter a character: ");
                scanf("\n%c", &item);
                insert(&startPtr, item);
                printList(startPtr);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (!isEmpty(startPtr)) {
                    printf("Enter character to be deleted: ");
                    scanf("\n%c", &item);
                    if (delete (&startPtr, item)) {
                        printf("%c deleted.\n", item);
                        printList(startPtr);
                    } else
                        printf(
                            "List is empty or the element doesn´t exist.\n\n");
                    break;
                    default:
                        printf("Invalid choice.\n\n");
                        instructions();
                        break;
                }
        }
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("End of run.\n");
    return 0;
}
void instructions(void) {
    printf(
        "Enter your choice:\n"
        "1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
        "2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
        "3 to end.\n");
}

char delete(LISTNODEPTR *sPtr, char value) {
    LISTNODEPTR previousPtr, currentPtr, tempPtr;
    // if (value == (*sPtr)->data){
    if (value == (*sPtr)->data) {
        tempPtr = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
        free(tempPtr);
        return value;
    } else {
        previousPtr = *sPtr;
        currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
        while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value) {
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        if (currentPtr != NULL) {
            tempPtr = currentPtr;
            previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            free(tempPtr);
            return value;
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}

int isEmpty(LISTNODEPTR sPtr) { return sPtr == NULL; }

void printList(LISTNODEPTR currentPtr)

{
    if (currentPtr == NULL) printf("List is empty. \n\n");
    while (currentPtr != NULL) {
        printf("%p %c -->", currentPtr, currentPtr->data);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
}
LISTNODE *addtoList(LISTNODE *sPtr, char value)
{
    LISTNODE* temp = malloc(sizeof(LISTNODE));
    if(temp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        temp->data = value;
        temp->nextPtr = NULL;       
    }
    if(sPtr == NULL)
    {
        sPtr = temp;
        return sPtr;
    }
    else
    if(sPtr != NULL && sPtr->nextPtr == NULL) 
    {
        sPtr->nextPtr = temp;
        return sPtr;
    }
    else
    if (sPtr != NULL && sPtr->nextPtr != NULL) 
    {
        LISTNODE* Head = sPtr;
        while(Head->nextPtr != NULL)
        {
            Head = Head->nextPtr;
        }
        Head->nextPtr = temp;
        return sPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown state of List\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused by the request - I'd expect that a circular linked list would offer the opposite - that the *last* item in the list points to the *first* item as its `next`. Typically, you'd make `insert` and `delete` maintain this particular invariant - can you work out (on paper) what insert and delete should do, conceptually?

Comment: Okay, yeah, I got confused it's the way you said it, the last item points to the first, sorry, I'll edit it now

Comment: It looks like your parapareses don't match up. Look at `case 2:` after I auto-formatted it.

Comment: If you are dealing with circular lists then every place you have `NULL` in your code is wrong. Except maybe `startPtr`. You have to consider how to represent an empty list.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow So you are saying that instead of `NULL`  I should use the head Pointer?

Comment: For the end of the list the next should point to the front of the list. The big problem is A) how do you represent an empty list and B) what do you pass to `insert()` so it can insert both into an empty list and an existing list. I always go with `void insert(LISTNODE **head, char value)` with `head == nullptr` for the empty list. Consider carefully the first and later inserts. Draw all the `LISTNODE` and `next` pointers and where `head` points to.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Could you make an example?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I am trying this bit of code to insert now (changed the code check in the main code)

Comment: What *problem do you hope to solve* by making the list circular? Is the list still intended to have a clear "beginning"? If so, who or what is responsible for keeping track of that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Honestly, I have to do it for an assignment, but I can't crack it, it has no other use than to store a char and show it

Answer (score 1):

With a circular list keeping track of the tail seems to have the fewest special cases and allows insertion at the front or back and deletion of the front in O(1). Deleting a node requires getting hold of their previous node. So iteration is best done with a pointer to the previous node kept in store.

So I made 2 structs: A ListNode that holds a pointer to the next node and the data. And a List that holds a pointer to the tail of the list. Although what the tail is in a circular list is arbitrary.

Operations on lists are always done by passing a `List *` in case the `List.tail` has to be updated. Operations that do not change the list take a `const List *`, e.g. `printList()`.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct ListNode
{
    struct ListNode *next;
    char data;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List
{
    ListNode *tail;
} List;

bool isEmpty(const List *list)
{
    return list->tail == NULL;
}

void printList(const List *list)
{
    if (isEmpty(list)) {
        printf("List is empty.\n\n");
        return;
    }
    // iteration works by keeping a pointer to the previous node
    // so we start at the tail to print the first node
    // it ends when the tail has been visited
    ListNode *p = list->tail;
    do {
        p = p->next;
        printf("%p %c -->", p, p->data);
    } while(p != list->tail);
    printf("\n\n");
}

char delete(List *list, char value)
{
    if (isEmpty(list)) return '\0';
    ListNode *p = list->tail;
    do {
        ListNode *q = p->next;
        if (q->data == value) {
            // remove q from list
            p->next = q->next;
            // are we removing the last node?
            if (p == q) list->tail = NULL;
            // if q is the tail set the tail to the previous node
            if (list->tail == q) list->tail = p;
            free(q);
            return value;
        }
        p = q;
    } while(p != list->tail);
    return '\0';
}

// add value to the end of the list
void insert(List *list, char value)
{
    // allocate node
    ListNode *node = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if (node == NULL) 
    {
        printf("'%c' not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
        exit(0);
    }
    node->data = value;
    // if list is empty point the tail at the new node
    if (isEmpty(list)) {
        list->tail = node;
    }
    // point the node at the head of the list
    node->next = list->tail->next;
    // point the tail node at the new node
    list->tail->next = node;
    // update the tail to the new node
    list->tail = node;
}

void instructions(void);

int main() {
    List list = { NULL };
    int choice;
    char item;

    instructions();
    do {
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a character: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &item);
            insert(&list, item);
            printList(&list);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (!isEmpty(&list)) {
                printf("Enter character to be deleted: ");
                scanf("\n%c", &item);
                if (delete (&list, item)) {
                    printf("'%c' deleted from list.\n", item);
                    printList(&list);
                } else {
                    printf("'%c' not found in list.\n", item);
                }
            } else {
                printf("List is empty.\n\n");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.\n\n");
            instructions();
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    printf("End of run.\n");
    return 0;
}

void instructions(void)
{
    printf(
        "Enter your choice:\n"
        "1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
        "2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
        "3 to end.\n");
}
```